# My bootstrap website is working locally, but fails to load css and images when trying to publish it

Tags: html, css, web, hosting

I'm pretty much new to all of this and for the past days I've been working on my first Website using bootstrap. Locally, this works fine, but right now, when trying to get it up online, it looks like this:

http://wearemanjaro.de

Just ugly html, no css nor any images are loading.
I made the link above link to the html which is in the /manjarowebsitebootrap/robots/index.html path. The CSS (bootstrap and custom) is in the following directory: /manjarowebsitebootstrap/css/...

The link to CSS in my html looks like the following:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/custom.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/bootstrap.min.css">
```

Same problem with the images in my ../img folder. It all works fine locally. I'd really love some help or advice :)

Comment: First check the requests in your browsers development console, most likely they fail. Then check your http servers error log file.

Comment: Can you show your map structure, don't see a css file in a map below your html normally

Comment: The location http​:​​​​​//wearemanjaro.de​/ doesn't have a .. folder.

Comment: In your site any link open same code.

Comment: view-source:http://wearemanjaro.de/css/bootstrap.min.css In bootstrap also open html file.

Answer (score 1):

First thing you need to do is use an absolute instead of a relative path.
if your directory structure is:

```
-root
--docs
---doc1.php

--includes
---header.php
---footer.php
---css.css

--index.php
```

In your header, you link to my CSS file like so:

```
<link href="includes/styling.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

you need to do like this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/root/includes/css.css" />
```

You also need to use developer tools on chrome that will help you to debug these things.
I saw there that the images are not uploaded so once you able to upload them you will start getting them on the Website if the path is correct.

and best of luck for the new world of web development.:)

Answer (score 0):

Your file structure has changed from local to online/live. I inspected your page, placed in the CDN for Bootstrap and pow, the styling came alive.

Use the following CDN to replace your current `src=''` path for bootstarp in your html head to see what I mean.

`https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css`

The next steps you should take: make note of where all your files are living on your server, you must place all associated files on the server, as specified by your code, i.e shows that you have a CSS folder.

Also is this HTML file located at the same level as the CSS folder or does this HTML file live in a folder of its own. If not your paths do not need to include the `../` portion and you should use just `css/yourFileName.css`